# How to use PHP to delete data from SQL?

Tags: php, sql

This is my PHP code for displaying sql data

```
<?php 

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","registration"); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{ 
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error()); 
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM goal WHERE userid = $_SESSION[userid]";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if($result == false) {
    die("Query failed: ".mysqli_error($con).PHP_EOL.$query);
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
{ 

echo "<div><br><br></div>";
echo "<p style='font-size: 16px'>"."<strong>".'Weight to lose: '.$row['weightlost']."</strong>"."</p>\n";
echo "<p style='font-size: 16px'>"."<strong>".'Weight unit: '.$row['weightunit']."</strong>"."</p>\n";
echo "<p style='font-size: 16px'>"."<strong>".'Date of when to lose the weight by: '.$row['whenby']."</strong>"."</p>\n";
echo "</div>";
echo "<form method='POST'>"."<input type='submit' value='Delete'>"."</form>\n";

} 
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

I've added a delete button. I'm trying to allow my users to click this delete button so they can delete particular goals they've set for themselves.

In sql, one goal consists of 'Weight to lose', 'Weight unit' and 'Data of when to lose the weight by'.

Comment: so where did you close off your form? if this is db-related to DELETE FROM table, where's that? and did you start the session and does that session array hold value?

Comment: Just to clarify your question's title. You can't use HTML to delete data from a database. You use a server script for that job.

Comment: Just corrected it. There is a session start further at the top and there's no value.

Comment: *"There is a session start further at the top and there's no value"* - and how do you expect your query / SELECT to work then? and how are you using this, as `http://localhost` or as `file:///`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much with php. I'm a beginner with this

Comment: *"I don't know much with php. I'm a beginner with this"* - **Again;** how are you using this, as `http://localhost` or as `file:///` and do you not have a webserver/php/mysql installed? These questions need to be answered fully. @m1234

Comment: Also, you should be using PDO instead of mysql or mysqli functions, as they're vulnerable to SQL Injections

Comment: @zack6849 PDO is still vulnerable to SQL injections if you don't make use of parameters. You should instead point out that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and should be avoided.

Comment: ok @m1234 you're not responding to [an **important** comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42723867/how-to-use-php-to-delete-data-from-sql#comment72567786_42723867) I left you. You will need to take it up with the answers that were given below. I've done what I could here, good luck.

Comment: Sorry, i'm using `http://localhost` and I do have a webserver/php/mysql installed

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ID field in your database (which you should) just add input type hidden with ID and it will work.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
{ 

echo "<div><br><br></div>";
echo "<p style='font-size: 16px'>"."<strong>".'Weight to lose: '.$row['weightlost']."</strong>"."</p>\n";
echo "<p style='font-size: 16px'>"."<strong>".'Weight unit: '.$row['weightunit']."</strong>"."</p>\n";
echo "<p style='font-size: 16px'>"."<strong>".'Date of when to lose the weight by: '.$row['whenby']."</strong>"."</p>\n";
echo "</div>";
echo "<form action='delete.php' method='POST'><input type='hidden' name='id' value='{$row['id']}'><input type='submit' value='Delete'></form>";

}
```

then in delete.php

```
<?php 

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","registration"); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{ 
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error()); 
}

$id=intval($_POST['id']);
$query = "delete from goal WHERE userid = $_SESSION[userid] and id='$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if($result == false) {
    die("Query failed: ".mysqli_error($con).PHP_EOL.$query);
}
?>
```

Comment: you're leaving them wide open to a serious sql injection

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oops.Thanks. My bad. fixed. intval should take care of it.

Comment: Welcome, yet I think you should look at the (new) comments under their question. I feel this one stands to take some time.

Comment: Just tried this, however, it deletes all the goals except one. I just need it to delete one goal that the user picks from the displayed screen.

Comment: @m1234 do you have a goal id associated with it? Can you show your table structure? Or do you just have one row with all the goals?

Comment: Yeah I do. So in my database I have a goal table. The attributes are id, weightlost, weightunit, whenby and userid. Userid is a foreign key.

Comment: eh, wait. When you say deletes all goals except one... you mean that you have 15 goals associated with one person, but when you click delete it deletes 14 goals and leaves just 1?

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what happens

Comment: @m1234 huh... that really should not happen. Is ID field in your goals table an `INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`? Is there any way you can upload some of your project on github or pastebin with mysqldump output so we can get a better picture of what's happening?

Comment: Yeah the ID field is an `INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` . I'm not a member on those sites :/ What exactly do you want to see?

Comment: @m1234 I just created my version of your code that works fine on my side. http://pastebin.com/dVfEHtHx (I did not do the session nor user id thing for simplicity). See if there are any clear differences between my version and your code.

Comment: Thanks for that! I'm just checking over it now. What's PDO?

Comment: PDO is what you should be using for all of your database connections. Read this guide. https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: Oh i see... i was using this `$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","registration"); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno())`

Answer (score 0):

In order to ensure you are tracking items properly, it is recommended that you have an auto_increment id field.  You can create one via a query like:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

Refer to https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp for help.

Then, I would add the id to the page via a hidden field (so the user doesn't see the id, which s/he doesn't need to see).

```
echo "<form action='post'><input name='id' type='hidden' value='" . $row['id'] . "'>"."<input type='submit' value='Delete'></form>";
```

The PHP code is farely similar, but you have to change it to a delete sql query:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE [condition];
```

[Here's a reference.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-delete-query.htm)